# Why does StringVar().get() return a blank value in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I cannot figure out why the 'save' button is pressed, the value that gets put into the 'ChildName' variable is blank?

```
def AddClassMember():
    global ChildNameEntryVariable
    global AddClassMemberWindow

    AddClassMemberWindow = Tk()

    ChildNameEntryVariable = StringVar()
    ChildNameEntry = Entry(AddClassMemberWindow, textvariable = ChildNameEntryVariable)
    ChildNameEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)
    ChildNameEntrySave = Button(AddClassMemberWindow, text = "save", command = SaveChildName)
    ChildNameEntrySave.grid(row=1,column=1)

def SaveChildName():
    PupilName = ChildNameEntryVariable.get()

    with db:
        cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Pupil Information' (PupilNames) VALUES (?)''', ([PupilName, ]))
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to add this in. Nothing to do with the database since when I try to print the variable it just returns as a blank value

Comment: Declaring `ChildNameEntryVariable` as global doesn't change the result in the database and I don't have an `except:` anywhere :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a popup, isn't it? You have another tk window open somewhere, right? If so, the quick fix is to provide StringVar with the correct master:

```
AddClassMemberWindow = Tk()

ChildNameEntryVariable = StringVar(AddClassMemberWindow)
```

The proper fix is to remember never to use `Tk()` more than once in a program. If you need more windows, use the `Toplevel` widget to make them.

Comment: After hours of trying to work out why something was always blank, this finally sorted it! I had another tkWindow open that needed destroying first before it would work!